# How can I make tha language toolbar change the input layout globally in windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch the KeyboardLayout for all Application at once](https://superuser.com/questions/106722/how-to-switch-the-keyboardlayout-for-all-application-at-once)

When I switch the input layout, it changes on a **per-app basis** instead of working globally.

How can I make it change globally?
Now it's jumping back and forth.

I'm using the language toolbar on the taskbar to change the layout with the mouse. I've disabled switching with keyboard since it mostly only caused accidents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically the same question as the one described [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/106722/how-to-switch-the-keyboardlayout-for-all-application-at-once)

the posts refer to two programs:

[KBSwitch](http://www.tomseddon.plus.com/kbswitch/) 
and [Switch it!](http://www.switchit.ru/rus/Beta.htm)

hope that helps