# Setting one of two keyboards as default

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout

My netbook with Windows XP  came with a standard 101/102 keyboard, but I connected later a logitech HD Comppliant keyboard via USB to use with comfort at home. The problems is that when I take my netbook on the road, my standard 101/102 (Microsoft Natural PS/2 keyboard) doesn't respond like before connecting the second one as default. For example I will press key and for a letter and a number comes out.

My question is how do I set my keyboard that's part of my netbook as default again? Is there a precedure where I can switch back and forth, according to the keyboard I want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this Superuser thread.

> [Switching keyboard layout in Windows globally](https://superuser.com/questions/13324/switching-keyboard-layout-in-windows-globally)

Also, here is a quick tuto about how to change keyboard layouts.

> http://www.conversationexchange.com/resources/keyboard-language.php

Hope this help and I understood your question correctly.