# Keyboard layouts switching randomly in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, laptop, synaptics-touchpad

I use the `US` and `United States-International` (`INTL`) keyboard layouts, since I occasionally need to type characters not normally found in English.  I rarely use the `INTL` layout intentionally.  However, Windows is constantly switching to it.  I am definitely not physically pressing the `Win + Space` key combination to switch layouts.

From what I can tell, this happens while I'm using the touchpad (Synaptics) on my laptop.  I have problems with the Synaptics drivers interfering with games by briefly removing focus from them when I scroll, and occasionally sending a `Ctrl` keystroke, so it would not surprise me in the least if Synaptics is responsible.  It never seems to happen *while* I'm typing, only between typing.

**Edit:**

It's probably important to mention that I've been having this problem since the days of XP Pro.  I've never used anything besides x64 in the time since I started using multiple keyboard layouts.  Most of my OSes come from TechNet or MSDN (retail, US), but I've also used betas, previews, and OEM releases.  I tend to use the Pro/Ultimate versions.  I've had the problem even after disabling the keyboard shortcut if I recall correctly, but it's been a while since I've done that; it's really not an option in Windows 8 anyway, since the taskbar isn't always visible.

I use Linux quite a bit.  I want to say I've set the equivalent shortcut in GNOME to `Alt + Shift` and didn't have the same problem, but it's been a while.  I still cringe whenever I hold `Alt` and `Shift` together, and I often repeat `Alt + Shift` if I perform an incomplete shortcut that uses those two keys out of habit.  I'm pretty sure that keyboard shortcut isn't the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem on my HP Envy 15 laptop, which also has a Synaptics touchpad.

Comment: This answer helped me: http://superuser.com/questions/13324/switching-keyboard-layout-in-windows-globally?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There is a Shortcut which switches through your installed languages:

Left Alt + Shift

It may be the problem. Right-Click the Language Toolbar in the Taskbar and go to Settings>Advanced Settings / check the Shortcut Settings there.

Comment: This is Windows 8.  None of that is relevant.  See the original question for the current keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Well i use Windows 7 and 8.... **the Shortcut does in fact change the layout** on both versions

Comment: It will only change the layout on Windows 8 if you are using multiple languages (which I am not).

Comment: >>> I use the US and United States-International (INTL) keyboard layouts

Comment: Then you have some weird configuration, because that's not how Windows 8 works.  See: Google (Anyway, it's irrelevant, because it doesn't work with my configuration.)

Comment: [Microsoft Shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/new-keyboard-shortcuts#1TC=t1) it goes on saying "With Windows 8 and Windows RT, you can use the keyboard shortcuts you're already using, and you'll find new ones too." Just trying to help.

Comment: Many of the old shortcuts work, but some of them don't, or are remapped to new (often unrelated) tasks.  That being said, there is an option deep in the language settings to set the key combination for changing the **language**, and it defaults to `Alt + Shift`.  It's a desktop-only toolbar settings dialog, though, and does not exist in RT--I don't know if the keyboard shortcut still works.  The toolbar is also disabled by default, in favor of the RT switcher that also docks on the taskbar in desktop mode.  To get the actual toolbar, you have to manually enable it, by default.

Comment: Maybe if I found a way to revert to the old shortcut, it would work better...?  I've had this problem since XP, though, even when I disabled the shortcut.  I suppose that's probably key information that I should add to the OP.

Comment: Left Alt+Shift does not work for me, and I'm on Windows 8. I know the Win+Space is supposed to change the keyboard layout, but I'm definitely not pressing that when my keyboard layout changes randomly.