# Windows Japanese IME - Global input mode toggle instead of per-window

Tags: windows, ime

How can i make it so that the input mode of the Japanese IME is global, rather than per-window?

---

Expected behavior:

- Window **1** focused: (set mode to hiragana)
- Window **2** focused: (set mode to latin)
- Window **1** focused: (type something) → (latin text appears)

Actual behavior:

- Window **1** focused: (set mode to hiragana)
- Window **2** focused: (set mode to latin)
- Window **1** focused: (type something) → (hiragana text appears rather than latin) [???]

Comment: Is this Windows 7/8/10? I believe this is possible in Windows 8 http://superuser.com/questions/13324/switching-keyboard-layout-in-windows-globally

Comment: That question concerns switching between different IMEs. I'm asking about switching between different modes internal to the Japanese IME. Switching between, say, the English and Japanese IME is global by default, but the input modes internal to the Japanese IME (latin/hiragana/katakana/et cetera) are on a per-window basis for some obscene reason.

Comment: Oh ok. I don't know of a solution to that but there are shortcut keys if you are interested: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/japanese-ime-hiragana-toggle-keys/3b2ffa3e-29ee-4d5a-b65b-dc67c9c869fc

Comment: Also interested in this. There should be a global switch.