# Windows 7 changes right-click and folder items from display language to default language randomly

Tags: windows-7, language

I am using a Japanese Default Windows 7 Enterprise x64 with the English Language Pack installed. The Region and Language Settings have English as the Display Language with Input Language as Japanese (Japan) - Microsoft IME, Format as Japanese (Japan) and location as Japan for Current User, Welcome Screen and New User Accounts. Installed Keyboard Layouts are English (US), Japanese (Japan) and English (Australia).

When right-clicking on blank space within a folder (and at times on files / folders themselves), the display language for both the right-click menu as well as the display name of all folders and headings automatically changes to Japanese until the folder is closed. If the folder is not closed and the control panel is opened, this also causes certain elements in the control panel to return to Japanese.

An uninstall and re-install of the English Language Pack has not yielded any difference. The problem began a week or so ago and may have been caused by an update, however I would not know which one.

**TLDR; How to fix the Windows 7 language display settings to not automatically change context menus and file menus to the default language after a right-click.**

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time researching this for you and it appears to be an issue in Win7 where the language settings are not global. This thread discusses how using a third party app to make the languages global seem to solve it. http://superuser.com/questions/13324/switching-keyboard-layout-in-windows-globally  From what I have read on TechNet, this behavior was improved in Win8 and was mostly eliminated in Win10.

Comment: Users state that this problem got worse over time leading one to believe it is some sort of corruption and that reinstalling the OS fixed it. I assume you would like to avoid that, so letting a 3rd part utility control it sounds like a good workaround.

Comment: @RandySchuman I have spent many hours stuffing around with this over the years and all computers handle it differently. Unfortunately, work has decided we stay on Windows 7 for the time being so no easy fixes. I have reinstalled before and had it fix itself too. However, at the moment I can't. Just for clarification, in that link, which app were you referring to? (There were a few mentioned)

Comment: Keyla is the one that claims to hold the settings globally. https://code.google.com/archive/p/keyla/downloads  I was hoping to find an article that would say to just delete some registry keys and reinstall the languages, but no dice.

Comment: More software here - http://alternativeto.net/software/punto-switcher/

Comment: @RandySchuman I have tried all manner of deleting and changing registry keys, but for every key you change, there is another key that Windows falls back to that happens to be the installed Windows version. I will try the software you said when I have time and get back to you with how it went.

Comment: Also bear in mind, what I am wanting to do has little to nothing to do with the keyboard layouts - which don't seem to affect the UI.